# Scroll View in Relative Layout

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1E1E1E"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ld"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 3"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ld"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ld"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="Botton 2"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ld"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 3"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ld"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 4"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ld"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 5"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Button 6"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:weightSum="6" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/b1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home1"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/abt"
            android:text="About"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ser"
            android:text="Services"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/cnt1"
            android:text="Portfolio"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/spt"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/inbox"
            android:text="Marketing"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I Need to have scroll view in the relative layout with fixed footer. the table layout alone should have scroll view and footer should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Add a scroll view as a parent of your TableLayout and align it above bottom layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1E1E1E" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:weightSum="6" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/b1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home1"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/abt"
            android:text="About"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ser"
            android:text="Services"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/cnt1"
            android:text="Portfolio"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/spt"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textSize="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/b6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/inbox"
            android:text="Marketing"
            android:textSize="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottombar" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ld"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Button 3"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ld"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ld"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="Botton 2"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ld"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Button 3"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ld"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Button 4"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/ld"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Button 5"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#000"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Button 6"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your top level and add to it what you need:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/footer">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your given xml code add a scroll view and replace your TableLayout inside it. Like this,Let it be first layout.

```
    <RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#1E1E1E">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
//contents inside table layout


</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now create another footer Layout,like this,let it be second layout.

```
 <RelativeLayout>
 //things to be appeared on footer are added here
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Inside your java code,get both the layouts using their ids, set the second layout as footter to the first layout.

```
firstlayout.addFooterView(secondlayout);
```

Now you can get a fixed footer and scrolling will be only within the first layouts table layout.

Comment: I am getting this error in xml    java.lang.NullPointerException Copy stack to clipboard

Comment: to what variable you are getting that exception?. please provide the detailed log if possible.